# How to display x or y values within the figure Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to display the x (or y) values within my figure in Matplotlib (like the following figure.). Can anyone guide me with that?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html).
Here is a code example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Y = np.random.rand(10, 1)
X = np.arange(10)
plt.plot(X, Y)
for x, y in zip(X, Y):
    plt.annotate(text=str(y[0])[:5], xy=(x, y))
plt.show()
```

Will output this:
[image]

Notice that `text` is a string so you can add either `x` or `y` or both if you'd like.